# Google.logInAsync does nothing

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

Expo SDK Version: 38.08
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS and Android
I am using the expo client on iOS for testing.

I added OAuth 2.0 Client IDs from Google APIs.

The Google.logInAsync function does nothing.

Here’s a snippet of my code :
Note : In the actual implementation I replaced iOSCLIENTID and androidCLIENTID with the actual IDs

```
async function signInWithGoogleAsync() {
try {
  const result = await Google.logInAsync({
    androidClientId: androidCLIENTID,
    behavior: "web",
    iosClientId: iOSCLIENTID,
    scopes: ["profile", "email"],
  });
  if (result.type === "success") {
    return result.accessToken;
  } else {
    return { cancelled: true };
  }
} catch (e) {
  return { error: true };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion it was a really silly mistake on my end. I didn't pass the CLIENTID as type string